# Feedback: "Was this post useful to you?" So that information is used for?

Tags: discussion

[image]

Anonymous users(who have no account or are not logged on exchange) have this feedback option. What does it stands for? Is this information used for some kind of ranking or something related?

Comment: *anonymous, who have, or are not ... , or something related?

Comment: 10k+ have option to view the post feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We moderators have access to some graph to track how much we get:

[image]

And [users have access to it on the tools page](https://superuser.com/tools/post-feedback)

[image]

The latter let's you see questions that are underrated or overrated, which can be a good idea for users to keep an eye out for. Perhaps there are questions that have a lot of votes, but are actually wrong and needs correcting.

Comment: Moderators you mean 10k+ rep users?

Comment: The top graph is for moderators only, the latter may or may not be 10k tools, I have no way to check it myself

Comment: I couldn't see on tools page too, its only for 10k rep users too...

Comment: We 10k (20k even) don't get the fancy graphs. Wonder why.

Comment: All the info is probably in the Post Feedback page, if you sort it by day/week. All in all, I hardly ever look at it, because its only 12 votes on like 100+ questions